Best Practice for Closing Flutter App Programmatically on Background Exit (Play Store and App Store Acceptance)
I'm developing a Flutter application and I need to implement a feature where the app can be closed programmatically when it goes into the background. I understand that directly closing the app using SystemNavigator.pop() for Android and exit() for iOS is generally accepted by both the Google Play Store and the Apple App Store. However, I want to ensure that I'm following best practices and providing a smooth user experience.
